# session is works locally but not online

Tags: php, authentication, session

The session is working on the result.php page but other page is undifined index. So session is not working. Can you help me please.

```
    session_regenerate_id(true);
    $_SESSION["ss_user_name"] = $username;
    $_SESSION['ss_password'] = $password;
    $_SESSION['loginIP'] = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $_SESSION['userAgent'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Comment: Session modifications are always only applied after `session_start()` is called, and before you send any page contents, as these operations are applied at the moment when headers are sent. When are you calling this script?

Comment: I wrote in the first line of all pages

Comment: Can you try to write `session_start()` right above your code?